# How can I update values in the correct location?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make a better unit converter than the one at [Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=feet%20to%20inches)

When I change the unit in the bottom box, it changes the number in the bottom box. I want the number in the bottom box to stay the same, and I want the top box to change number. I already have the top box not changing numbers when I change the unit; just need the bottom box to not change numbers. Here is my code:

```js
//Distance Math

var units = [
  ['Inches', 0.025400000000000],
  ['Feet', 0.30480000000000000],
  ['Furlongs', 201.168],
  ['Meters', 1.00]
];
var selectors = document.querySelectorAll('.newClass1');

for (var i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < selectors.length; j++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = units[i][1];
    option.textContent = units[i][0];
    selectors[j].add(option);
  }
}

function updateInputBox2() {
  var SpecialValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthInput1").value) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthCalc1").value) / parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthCalc2").value);

  document.getElementById("lengthInput2").value = SpecialValue;

}

function updateInputBox1() {
  var SpecialValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthInput2").value) * parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthCalc2").value) / parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthCalc1").value);

  document.getElementById("lengthInput1").value = SpecialValue;
}
    
    



//MYSTIC STUFF

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.select2-selection--single{height:100px !important}

.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
 
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="STYLE.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Javascript -->

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Mechanics</title>
</head>

<body>

                                <!-- LENGTH ACCORDION -->
                                <button class="accordion">Length &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CLICK ME &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; OR&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;            TAP ME!</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>From:</p>
  <select style="float:left" id="lengthCalc1" class="js-example-basic-single select2-container newClass1" oninput="updateInputBox2()" onchange="updateInputBox2()">
  </select>
  <input style="height:50%;font-size:15pt;width:1000px; border: 1px solid #000;" id="lengthInput1" type="number" oninput="updateInputBox2()" />
  <p>To:</p>
  <select style="float:left" id="lengthCalc2" class="js-example-basic-single select2-container newClass1" oninput="updateInputBox2()" onchange="updateInputBox2()">
  </select>
  <input style="height:50%;font-size:15pt;width:1000px; border: 1px solid #000;" id="lengthInput2" type="number" oninput="updateInputBox1()" onchange="updateInputBox1()" />
</div>                              
        <link href="
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css
" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
            });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: It's working fine for me. Not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: déjà vu .... keep asking the same question

Comment: When I edit the units of the bottom box, the number changes in the bottom box. I want the number of the top box to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `updateInputBox2()` in as both onInputs. Try changing one of them to `updateInputBox1()`.

Comment: You did it! Thanks!